# « Et que cela saute ! »

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, interjections, origine-ou-raison

De quelle origine provient cette expression ? « Et que cela saute ! ». Est-ce que le « Et », qui est vraiment obligatoire dans cette phrase, a une signification spéciale ? Que veut dire « sauter » dans ce cas-ci ?

Comment: J'aimerai rajouter en complément de la réponse que les francophones diront plutôt « Et que *ça* saute ! », ou pour les plus pressés, « Et *qu'ça* saute ! ». De manière générale, à l'oral, on préférera utiliser *ça* plutôt que *cela*, qui est à réserver pour un cadre plus formel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Un des sens de [*sauter*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sauter) est *se précipiter*, ce qui doit être précipité, c'est l'exécution des demandes antérieures (le TLFi donne d'ailleurs l'expression avec ce sens).

Quant au *et*, pour moi c'est la conjonction normale dans un emploi similaire à celui dans *Tu peux aller acheter des œufs ?... Et regarde s'il y a du lait aussi.*